# Best way to automate Postgres logical database pg_dumps within AWS

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pg-dump

Looking for a way to automate pg_dumps from all logical databases for all of our RDS instances and then send those dumps to s3. I see using AWS Batch as a solution but that involves a lot of services like Lambda that I do not have a background in. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you can "buy" instead of make, that's what I would go with. Simplebacks works well for us

Comment: Have any info I can read about "Simplebacks". I have never heard of them and google is failing me.

Comment: Sorry I misspelled Simplebackups. It's a paid service, affordable, highly recommended. Does exactly what you need

Comment: Technically , all u need is a server to run ur pgdump. Although not the use case, code build will allow u to run/install what u want on an Unix environment on demand. This can be scheduled as well.

Comment: This seems way better https://github.com/Birne94/rds-s3-database-backup

Comment: @ChaseMitchell yes you can roll your own database backups. But consider the cost in: your time setting up, your time maintaining, your time handling errors, how will you alert your team that a backup has failed, how will your custom code retry backups when they fail, as your database grows your server that performs the backup will also need to scale up. I could go on and on :)  Typically for a commercial environment, paying for a service to do something mission critical like this is well worth the cost in dollars